# How to use different host with quartz depending on trigger?

Tags: c#, quartz-scheduler, jobs, quartz

I need to programmatically choose which scheduler to use for a certain job based on trigger. 
I don't know where I have to tackle.

This is the quartz app config section:

```
 <quartz>
    <add key="quartz.scheduler.instanceName" value="ServerScheduler" />

    <add key="quartz.threadPool.type" value="Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz" />
    <add key="quartz.threadPool.threadCount" value="10" />
    <add key="quartz.threadPool.threadPriority" value="Normal" />

    <add key="quartz.scheduler.exporter.type" value="Quartz.Simpl.RemotingSchedulerExporter, Quartz" />
    <add key="quartz.scheduler.exporter.port" value="555" />
    <add key="quartz.scheduler.exporter.bindName" value="QuartzScheduler" />
    <add key="quartz.scheduler.exporter.channelType" value="tcp" />

    <add key="quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold" value="40000" />
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.type" value="Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz" />
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.dataSource" value="default" />
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix" value="QRTZ_" />
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.clustered" value="true" />
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.maxMisfiresToHandleAtATime" value="40" />
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.lockHandler.type" value="Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.UpdateLockRowSemaphore, Quartz" />
    <add key="quartz.dataSource.default.connectionString" value="Integrated Security=SSPI;Pooling=false;Data Source=(local)\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=XXX" />
    <add key="quartz.dataSource.default.provider" value="SqlServer-20" />
  </quartz>
```

Then our service looks like this:

```
public void ScheduleJob(ITrigger trigger)
        {
            IScheduler scheduler = WMSScheduler.GetScheduler();

            try
            {
                scheduler.ScheduleJob(trigger);
            }
            catch (SocketException)
            {
                throw new Exception(CaptionHelper.GetLocalizedText(@"Messages\Common", "QuartzNotRunning"));
            }
        }


public static IScheduler GetScheduler()
        {
            if (scheduler == null)
            {
                scheduler = BuildScheduler();
            }

            return scheduler;
        }

  public static bool IsSchedulerStarted()
        {
            string proxyAddress = GetProxyAddress();

            Uri uri;
            if (Uri.TryCreate(proxyAddress, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute, out uri))
            {
                return IsPortListening(uri);
            }

            throw new InvalidOperationException("The configured Scheduler address is incorrect.");
        }
```

This functionality wasn't developed by me so I am still learning and trying to understand how this works.

As I understood at this moment there are 2 Quartz hosts at 2 servers and we can not indicate what is done by which Quartz host but sometimes we want to steer on which server is done what.

Any idea?

Comment: Do you still need clustered mode if you want to restrict which job gets executed on what node?

Comment: Yes, that is due to the fact that one of our clients has this scenario:

client has 2 servers:
1. with website A & quartz
2. With website B, 10 Workflow hosts and Quartz

If we are using a specific workflow that will use a lot of resources from server B. That is why we want that by that time only certain jobs will be executed by quartz on server B, like printing. Other heavier jobs we want to be executed only by server A at that moment.

Otherwise, when we know that server B is not that busy we want to configure that we could use at full potential all quartz hosts.